# How is this "bread" puffing up without yeast or baking soda?

Tags: flatbread

I have seen versions of the recipe in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vk68HMjQiqc)- the recipe is just flour, water, and fat (looks like a crepe) but it appears to puff up like a tortilla/paratha. See [2:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vk68HMjQiqc&t=2m31s)

I have never been able to make it bubble up like in the video.

Comment: I don't want to steal view from the youtuber but I think I should post the ingredients for users who don't want to open a youtube link just mix the following;
✤ Ingredients (makes 6)
  - 200g All-purpose flour
  - 3g (1tsp) Salt
  - 3g (1tsp) Sugar
  - 10g (1Tbsp) Melted unsalted butter
  - 18g (1Tbsp) Minced garlic
  - 25g (2.5Tbsp) Chopped green onion
  - 380ml Water

Comment: In my experience it doesn't really matter whether it puffs up like that or not. All that puff disappears as it cools down anyway, and the end product is all that matters. If your bread tastes good then don't worry about that puff.

Comment: @JackAidley as a side, yes, but if you want to fill it like pitta, you do want one big bubble

Comment: @ChrisH Sure, but the style of bread in that video is not one that you stuff.

Comment: @JackAidley it's not the sort *you* stuff.  Others might, if it formed a pocket; I might depending on what I was having with it

Comment: @JackAidley I have never been able to make it puff up like in the video but I have seen other videos that managed to make it puff. The bread does taste good- basically a thick crepe. But I was curious why mine never puffed up...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One word: Steam.

This is a rather liquid batter, so during the cooking process, the water evaporates and generates a generous amount of steam. When the pancake/flatbread outside has set, the steam has no way to escape, and thus puffs up the bread and creates first multiple pockets, that the cook then gently taps to join into one or a few large ones.

The “trick” is to get the outside set early on, to trap lots of steam. In the video, the cook starts at medium-low and turns as early as possible (-> closed skin), then increases the heat (-> steam & puffing up).

Comment: The trick might well lead to needing a hot pan, to seal the first underside, then an early flip before the middle gets too hot, and possibly a second flip to finish off that first sealed face. You'll need to experiment, but a hotter pan would be a good place to start

Comment: I will have to try to experiment with the heat more I guess, but every time I tried to make it, it just turned into a thick crepe. Still quite good, but I never managed to get any layering.

Comment: Try it in a hot oven. Either as hot as yours goes, or a hot as you are comfortable making yours go (and beware of using non-stick pans that either won't go that hot, or that set a limit lower than the oven's maximum temp) no flip and both sides get a skin.

Comment: Getting this to work can take a bit of practice. The way it puffs up in the video looks very similar to when I make pita bread or tortillas using a cast iron skillet. The technique I use is based on Melissa Guerra's instructions in _Dishes from the Wild Horse Desert_ for tortillas; the full passage is too long to quote here, but the essence is that you get the skillet very hot, then put the flatbread on it for a short period of time to "seal" (e.g. 20 s.), then flip, and when you see brown dots forming on the underside (eg. 2 m.), flip it again. It will poof. Get it good and poofed; done.

Comment: @Ecnerwal flatbreads are why I bought one of my enamelled cast iron pans (oven or hob).  But in the oven a pizza stone is another option